# How can I put the main-text div to the left and main-img to right? The some area of main-text should above the main-img div. Like in the photo?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overlap

[image]

```css
.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  width: 674px;
  display: inline-block;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
   
.main-img {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
    
.main h1 {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-text">
    <h1>Find your custom matched commercial real estate space.</h1>
    <p>
      In oculis quidem exercitus quid ex ea consequatur? autem vel eum
      fugiat, quo pertineant ero tibique
    </p>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="&#xf003; Your email address"
        style="font-family: Arial, FontAwesome"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="main-img"><img src="building.png" alt="building" /></div>
</div>
```

Hello everyone
I want to clone CutSpace website.

How can I put the main-text div to the left and main-img to the right? Some areas of main-text should above the main-img div. Like on the photo?

Comment: Try `float: left` on `.main-text`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a grid for the main layout, then use a negative right margin on the heading to get it to stretch into the space for the right column, and finally put a positive z-index on the left column to get it to display in front of the right column.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.main-text {
  z-index: 10;
}
   
.main-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
    
.main h1 {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: -30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-text">
    <h1>Find your custom matched commercial real estate space.</h1>
    <p>
      In oculis quidem exercitus quid ex ea consequatur? autem vel eum
      fugiat, quo pertineant ero tibique
    </p>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="&#xf003; Your email address"
        style="font-family: Arial, FontAwesome"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="main-img"><img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/73/114973-050-2DC46083/Midtown-Manhattan-Empire-State-Building-New-York.jpg" alt="building" /></div>
</div>
```